# how do you easily create tables in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, h2

I have a spring mvc project that needs to create a bunch of tables. The source of the table data is from a non-SQL, remote data source that isn't available until after the user logs in. I can create dummy rows in DataConfiguration.initDatabase and then truncate each table. If I don't do that, then when I try to insert data in other places in the code, the reference to the repository is null.

Since I have quite a number of tables and they use referential integrity, is there a way to declare them in such a way that they are automatically created without actually inserting any data?

I am using Java configuration.

Comment: "I can create dummy rows in DataConfiguration.initDatabase and then truncate each table" ??? I'm sorry but this is unclear. You should try to explain what you are trying to achieve. Where are you trying to create tables, for what purpose, ...

Comment: I am hauling a bunch of data from remote sites into my app. The data on those sites is not accessed via database connections. The data is of various types from various systems. By convention, the userids and passwords on the remote systems is the same, however they are not protected by single sign on. As a result I have built a custom login which uses LDAP. Once the user is logged in, I can then retrieve the data from the various remote systems. I can't seem to get my internal tables built unless I do it from DataConfiguration.initDatabase with insert statements in a ResourceDataPopulator.

Comment: Continuing... Since I don't have the real data at the time initDatabase is run, I insert dummy rows and then immediately truncate the table. That gets the table created so I can then populate it in my UsernanmePasswordAuthenticationProvider to actually build the tables. If I don't do the insert in the initDatabase, then when I try to populate the tables in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider, I get an exception. Can't remember the exact exception, but essentially it says the table doesn't exist. If I do the build in initDatabase, everything is fine.

Comment: Continuing... My understanding was that tables were created at first use. That's not working for me. Of course I'm missing something but I don't know what. I used the UserRepository as a model to get things working, but there must be a way to make this more "Springy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables were apparently created after all. Even when I looked in H2, I couldn't find them. Turns out I was looking in the default H2 connection "jdbc:h2:~/test" rather than "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb".